# CMake check_function_exists doesn't

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm working through the [CMake Tutorial](https://cmake.org/cmake-tutorial/) and cross-checking with the associated [project files](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/tree/master/Tests/Tutorial) and I'm stuck on Step 4.

The instructions add these lines to the top-level CMakeLists.txt file:

```
# does this system provide the log and exp functions?
include (CheckFunctionExists)
check_function_exists (log HAVE_LOG)
check_function_exists (exp HAVE_EXP)
```

As noted, this is a trivial test as just about every system on the planet has `log` and `exp`. But it fails. When generating the Makefiles, I see

```
-- Looking for log
-- Looking for log - not found
-- Looking for exp
-- Looking for exp - not found
```

If I dig deeper, running `cmake --trace`, I see the following lines:

```
.../tutorial/src/CMakeLists.txt(19):  include( CheckFunctionExists )
/usr/share/cmake/Modules/CheckFunctionExists.cmake(32):  macro(CHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS FUNCTION VARIABLE )
.../tutorial/src/CMakeLists.txt(20):  check_function_exists(log HAVE_LOG )
/usr/share/cmake/Modules/CheckFunctionExists.cmake(33):  if(HAVE_LOG MATCHES ^HAVE_LOG$ )
.../tutorial/src/CMakeLists.txt(21):  check_function_exists(exp HAVE_EXP )
/usr/share/cmake/Modules/CheckFunctionExists.cmake(33):  if(HAVE_EXP MATCHES ^HAVE_EXP$ )
```

In the `CheckFunctionExists.cmake` file, there is no `else` condition for that test. I'm new to cmake, but the tests appear true to my eye. What am I missing?

CentOS 7, cmake 2.8.12.2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`CheckFunctionExists` is known to have severe drawbacks. See [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/module/CheckFunctionExists.html).

In your case you likely run into the first pitfall. The functions `log` and `exp` are intrinsic **inline functions** on many platforms. They cannot be detected at link time.

The recommended **replacement is `CheckSymbolExists`**. Unfortunately this is not supported by your cmake version. You will need to upgrade at least to 3.0.2 for this to work.

Comment: the documentation on CheckSymbolExists is paltry. Can you offer a working example?

Comment: stumbling through, this seems to work:

`    include(CheckCXXSymbolExists)
    check_cxx_symbol_exists(log cmath HAVE_LOG)`